# changing how Setup.hs is built

Tags: haskell, cabal

The [encoding](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/encoding) package uses [HaXml](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml) in its build script (in `Setup.hs`). It happens to use bits of the interface that changed between HaXml-1.19 and HaXml-1.22. It would be nice if the encoding package were able to build with either version. I tried using the usual Cabal trick, namely, doing something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
#if MIN_VERSION_HaXml(1,22,0)
-- HaXml-1.22 code
#else
-- HaXml-1.19 code
#endif
```

...but the magic defines can't exist before the package is configured, and this file is being built to make the configure step possible. What are my options? Is there a way to change the command that cabal-install calls to compile `Setup.hs`? Is there another mechanism for conditionally selecting code that sidesteps cabal?

Comment: How severe are the interface changes? What kind of changes are they? It's possible that template haskell may be able to rescue you, depending on what they are.

Comment: @benmachine The only real change is that the `Element` constructor now takes a value of type `data QName = N String | SomethingIDon'tCareAbout` instead of a `String`. The `Setup.hs` file uses the `Element` constructor both as a function (always with a literal `String`) and for pattern matching (sometimes with a literal `String` and sometimes with a catch-all variable pattern).

Comment: So would it suffice if you had functions `toQName` and `fromQName` such that when `QName` exists, `toQName = N` and `fromQName` turns `N s` into `Just s` (and anything else into `Nothing`), whereas when `QName` does not exist, `toQName = id` and `fromQName = Just`? Then you might be able to do what you want with view patterns? I think `toQName` and `fromQName` can be defined with template haskell, using ideas similar to that in my [notcpp package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/notcpp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Data.Data` interface is capable (just about!) of constructing and deconstructing values of a type that may or may not exist. Unfortunately, HaXml doesn't appear to have `Data` instances for its types, and you can't define one since you can't refer to the type that might or might not exist, so we have to resort to Template Haskell:

The following module exports `qnameCompat`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module HaXmlCompat (qnameCompat) where

import Language.Haskell.TH

qnameCompat :: Q [Dec]
qnameCompat = do
  mi <- maybeReify "N"
  case mi of
    Nothing -> sequence [
      tySynD (mkName "QName") [] [t| String |],
      valD [p| toQName |] (normalB [| id |]) [],
      valD [p| fromQName |] (normalB [| Just |]) []]
    Just (DataConI n _ _ _) -> do
      s <- newName "s"
      sequence [
        valD [p| toQName |] (normalB (conE n)) [],
        funD (mkName "fromQName") [
          clause [conP n [varP s]] (normalB (appE [| Just |] (varE s))) [],
          clause [ [p| _ |] ] (normalB [| Nothing |]) []]]
    Just i -> fail $
      "N exists, but isn't the sort of thing I expected: " ++ show i

maybeReify :: String -> Q (Maybe Info)
maybeReify = recover (return Nothing) . fmap Just . reify . mkName
```

When spliced at the top level using Template Haskell, `qnameCompat` will check if `N` exists. If it does, it produces the following code:

```
toQName = N
fromQName (N s) = Just s
fromQName _ = Nothing
```

If it doesn't, the following is produced:

```
type QName = String
toQName = id
fromQName = Just
```

Now you can create and deconstruct `Element`s, e.g. using the ViewPatterns extension:

```
myElt :: String -> Element i
myElt = Elem (toQName "elemName") [] []

eltName :: Element i -> String
eltName (Elem (fromQName -> Just n) _ _) = n
```

ViewPatterns is convenient, but not essential, of course: using ordinary pattern matching on the result of `fromQName` will work just as well.

(These ideas are what led me to develop the [notcpp package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/notcpp/0.2.0.2/doc/html/NotCPP-ScopeLookup.html), which includes `maybeReify` and some other useful utilities)

Answer (score 2):

There don't seem to be very many knobs in `cabal-install/Distribution/Client/SetupWrapper.hs` controlling the compilation of `Setup.hs`, so your best bet may be to create a stub Setup.hs file which performs the version test, and then hands off to real `Setup.hs` once it has figured out what the version is.

Another trick is to make a compatibility shim library which your Setup script uses, which has the appropriate version tricks.

But maybe the real question to ask, is this: why is `Setup.hs` using external libraries?

Comment: Hm, how will handing off help? Won't it still make an attempt to build (both) the thing(s) I'm handing off to?

Comment: Right, you need to reinvoke GHC with the appropriate macro definitions.